# Assign uniqueidentifier with multiple values

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I want to do this simple query:

```
USE First_db

DECLARE @appIDs uniqueidentifier;
SET @appIDs = (SELECT DISTINCT AppID FROM InternalAudit 
               WHERE ModelName = 'Quote' 
               ORDER BY AppID DESC);

USE Second_db

SELECT * FROM Quotes WHERE AppID IN (@appIDs)
```

The third line is causing an error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

I'm not sure how to get around this. I need to assign the `appIDs` to a variable since I need it on a different database.

How do I properly assign a `uniqueidentifier` with multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single (scalar) variable can only contain a single value - it cannot be populated with multiple different values from multiple records.

In essence, if you had a query - similar to yours - such as

```
SET @var = (SELECT id FROM myTable)
```

then if that query returned multiple records, the `@var` variable would (likely) be populated with just the "id" value of the last record in the dataset (or possibly the first ... in either case, only a single value).

Even if you want to query across different databases, then there is no specific need for you to try and capture the criteria values first, to then use in a second query.  You should be able to achieve your desired result with a single query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Second_db..Quotes
WHERE AppId IN (SELECT AppID 
                FROM First_db..InternalAudit
                WHERE ModelName = 'Quote');
```

Also, in relation to the specific error message that you noted in your question, that's just a standard SQL syntax error, which is essentially telling you about a specific problem with your 3rd line (as the error denotes, you can only include `ORDER BY` in a sub-query under certain circumstances, and your particular statement contravened the rule). In any case, because you can solve your problem by altering the way your query is structured, you will now avoid that particular error.